# Excel VBA Run Time Error 1004 "Application-Defined or Object-Defined Error"

Tags: vba, excel

I am writing a program that currently, when the user clicks "OK", saves the current file, copies certain values in the file; then pastes the values to a different file. Then both files close. My problem is that it gives me an error:

> Run Time Error: 'Application-Defined or Object Defined Error'

It highlights this line:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("data").Range("C31", Range("C106").End (xlToRight)).Copy
```

I separated this line and the one right after it to test it alone and it worked like I wanted to. I tested the rest of the program without those two lines and it worked like I expected it to.
I tried to limit it to just copying one cell and it worked.
I made sure that the name of the sheet was correct.
I tried to just copy one row:

```
Range("C31", range("C31").End(xlToRight))
```

it still did not work and I came across the same error message.
I want to say I referenced something wrong but I don't see it.
Any reply at all would be helpful, Thank you.

P.S. I am sorry for redundancy in the code, I don't use "Dim" as much as I should.

```
Sub Button425_Click()
Dim FName As String
Dim FPath As String
Dim yourmsg As String
Dim testmsg As String
yourmsg = "Are you sure that you want to save and exit?"
testmsg = MsgBox(yourmsg, vbOKCancel + vbExclamation)
FPath = "I:\a\d\f\daily log recycle\"
FName = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C3").Text
If testmsg = 1 Then
    ThisWorkbook.SaveAs filename:=FPath & "\" & FName
    Workbooks.Open ("I:\a\d\f\new daily log 1.xlsm")
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("data").Range("C31", Range("C31").End(xlToRight)).Copy
    Workbooks("new daily log 1.xlsm").Worksheets("data").Range("D31").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("E45").Copy
    Workbooks("new daily log 1.xlsm").Worksheets("sheet1").Range("E44").PasteSpecial
    Workbooks("new daily log 1.xlsm").Worksheets("sheet1").Range("E45").ClearContents
    Workbooks("new daily log 1.xlsm").Save
    Workbooks("new daily log 1.xlsm").Close
    ThisWorkbook.Saved = True
    Application.Quit
Else 'do nothing
End If
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're mixing a fully addressed range

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("data").Range("C31"
```

with a relatively addressed range

```
Range("C106").End (xlToRight)
```

Try

```
 ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("data").Range("C31", ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("data").Range("C106").End (xlToRight))
```

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple of issues:

```
FPath = "I:\a\d\f\daily log recycle\"
ThisWorkbook.SaveAs filename:=FPath & "\" & FName
```

When you attempt to save you will have `...\daily log recycle\\<filename>`. Remove one of the backslashes `\`, I'd suggest removing the one in the `.SaveAs` line.

Then, with these two lines:

```
Workbooks.Open ("I:\a\d\f\new daily log 1.xlsm")
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("data").Range("C31", Range("C31").End(xlToRight)).Copy
```

The `ThisWorkbook` probably isn't pointing to the one you think it is. On all the following lines you specify `Workbooks("new daily log 1.xlsm").`, why don't you replace `ThisWorkbook` with an explicit `Workbooks("...")` so you can be 100% certain of which of the two open workbooks you're referencing.

I would also do that for these two lines:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("E45").Copy
ThisWorkbook.Saved = True
```

Also, just to be clear, `ThisWorkbook.Saved = True` tells Excel to *not prompt* you to save the workbook when you close it, but it *doesn't* actually save the workbook. If you want to actually save it, you'll need to use `.Save`, just like you do a couple lines above that for `Workbooks("new daily log 1.xlsm").Save`.